# How to fix my code of reducing string sizes to their "effective size"

Tags: c, scanf, fgets, c-strings, strlen

I want to make a code that reads a string, and then tranposes this string into a new one with length equal to the effective length of the original string, that is,

```
old string = stringi      

new string = stringii

newstring[strlen(stringi)+1]  (where +1 is for the terminator '\0'
```

I do this for two strings (string 1 and string 2), and in the end I print ‍`strlen(string1)`, `strlen(string2)`, and print also string11 and `string22` (to see whether it worked).

Well, what's the problem? The program compiles right.

But if I type "sugar" for string 1 and "sugara" for string 2, it returns:
sugar
sugara'

Or if I type batata and cenoura it returns:
batata'
cenoura

Or if I type cenoura and batata it returns:
cenoura 
batata'

I don't know what's the motive of this problem. If anyone could help me searching for bugs in the code (or suggesting another alternative for doing the problem)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    //Here I create two strings with size 100
    char string1[100], string2[100];
    //Here I ask for the user to type two phrases and store them using gets
    printf("Type two phrases):\n");
    gets(string1);
    gets(string2);
    //Here I create two new strings with size given by strlen(stringi)+1
    char string11[strlen(string1)+1];
    char string22[strlen(string2)+1];
    //For string 1, I atrribute all the values of the original string to the new string, until '\0'
    for (int i = 0; string1[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        string11[i] = string1[i];
    }
    //Here I denote the last position of the new string with the terminator
    string11[strlen(string1)+1] = '\0';
    //I do the same for string 2
    for (int i = 0; string2[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        string22[i] = string2[i];
    }
    string22 [strlen(string2)+1] = '\0';
    //I print the length of the original strings and the new strings
    printf("length string 1 = %d  length string 2 = %d\n", strlen(string1), strlen(string2));
    printf("%s\n%s\n", string11, string22);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You wrote the string terminators to the wrong place, off by one. it should be `string11[strlen(string1)] = '\0';`

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I didn't read the complete question, but basically you want to store the string as per its original length. Well use [`strdup(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html).

Answer (score 3):

These statements

```
string11[strlen(string1)+1] = '\0';
tring22 [strlen(string2)+1] = '\0';
```

are wrong.

You have to write

```
string11[strlen(string1)] = '\0';
tring22 [strlen(string2)] = '\0';
```

This call is also wrong

```
printf("length string 1 = %d  length string 2 = %d\n", strlen(string1), strlen(string2));
```

You have to write

```
printf("length string 1 = %zu  length string 2 = %zu\n", strlen(string1), strlen(string2));
```

Pay attention to that the function `gets` is not a standard C function any more. Use instead `fgets`.

For example

```
fgets( string1, sizeof( string1 ), stdin );
string1[ strcspn( string1, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! But to be honest I didn't understand the logic of it.                          If strlen returns the number of components before '\0', then I create a new string with strlen(original_string) + 1 components. But why when copying do I attribute '\0' to the strlen'th component, and not to the component strlen +1?

Comment: @francescobfc If you have an array of N elements then the last element has the index equal to N - 1.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that, because it starts at 0. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Hello you didn't need to increment with 1 at initilisation of tables length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    //Here I create two strings with size 100
    char string1[100], string2[100];
    //Here I ask for the user to type two phrases and store them using         gets
    printf("Type two phrases):\n");
    gets(string1);
    gets(string2);
    //Here I create two new strings with size given by strlen(stringi)+1
    char string11[strlen(string1)];
    char string22[strlen(string2)];
    //For string 1, I atrribute all the values of the original string to the new string, until '\0'
    for (int i = 0; string1[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        string11[i] = string1[i];
    }
    //Here I denote the last position of the new string with the terminator
    string11[strlen(string1)] = '\0';
    //I do the same for string 2
    for (int i = 0; string2[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        string22[i] = string2[i];
    }
    string22 [strlen(string2)] = '\0';
    //I print the length of the original strings and the new strings
    printf("length string 1 = %d  length string 2 = %d\n", strlen(string1), strlen(string2));
    printf("%s\n%s\n", string11, string22);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

good luck.

Comment: Thanks! It also worked. But I have to admit I'm a bit confused. The program worked the same way with and without this 1. And it is worth of notice that I'm using string11[strlen(string1)] = '\0'; in both cases. My logic was: The string_original has 100 entries. Suppose the '\0' entry is in the fifth entry (49). Then strlen(string_original) should return 49 (number of entries before '\0'). Then, if I wanna copy string_original into new_string, I need to declare the latter with 50 entries (strlen(string_original) + 1), so that the last entry (number 49) can be attributed as '\0'.